# Does this equation has a non-trivial solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Suppose $u:[0,1]^2\to [0,1]$. The equation
$$\int_{[0,1]}\frac{\partial u}{\partial u_1} (y,x)dx=\int_{[0,1]}\frac{\partial u}{\partial u_2} (x,y)dx,    \phantom{00}\forall y\in[0,1]$$
has trivial constant solutions. Does it have nontrivial solutions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let $u(u_1,u_2)=u_1u_2$. Then $\displaystyle\frac{\partial u}{\partial u_1}(y,x)=x$, and 
$$\int_{[0,1]}\frac{\partial u}{\partial u_1}(y,x)dx=\int_0^1xdx=\frac{1}{2},$$
and $\displaystyle\frac{\partial u}{\partial u_2}(x,y)=x$, and 
$$\int_{[0,1]}\frac{\partial u}{\partial u_2}(x,y)dx=\int_0^1xdx=\frac{1}{2}.$$

Comment: Thanks. It is really helpful. My initial question is that whether $$\int_{[0,1]} u(y,x)-u(x,y) dx>0$$ could have a solution and it seems symmetric solution yield 0.